# Can I publish a limited subset of Google Analytics data?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have a static website with a lot of posts. I’d like to display a list of most-read posts based on my Analytics data, using Javascript, with no server-side support. The Analytics API would be perfect for this, but I don’t want to open all my Analytics data to the public. Are there any options?

Answer (score 0):

So far I have only found a solution using Google’s [superProxy](https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-super-proxy). Which means having a server component, but since it looks like it should be possible to fit in the free App Engine tier, I think I’ll give it a try.